# Eclipse Luna no syntax coloring

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, enums, syntax-highlighting

Well I have a problem with one of my classes in Eclipse. In there I define an inner Enum type.
In the picture you can see one of the enum-Constants:https: //www.dropbox.com/s/z9shh52au35mkzy/Pict1.JPG

Now I wanted to add some code to the "setup()" method. Sadly the syntax coloring for the new code doens't show up and even if I create a syntax error inside, it doesn't recognize it. (it works at other places)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/0t6que0pg1hr1tw/Pict2.JPG (can't put pictures in the question yet, I hope you don't mind if I put links there)

Finally, when I save the file and reopen it, the error behaviour is the same, but my pour code looks like this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9lqzchv4xrnpau6/Pict3.JPG

As you can see, even in the other enum constants, there is just color at keywords and things outside of methods. (If I remove the added code and reopen, it works as if nothing hab happened)

So my question is, how can I fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried what happens if you use the standard "bright" theme instead of a dark theme? Which Operating System do you use?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work either.
i've got windows 7 64bit

Comment: I have seen this happen when there are syntax errors. Like closing a class unintentional. Could you check this?

Comment: that isn't the case. I think I'll just live with it... but thank you both nervertheless :)